# InDesign CS5 Script: How can you display a directory?

Tags: directory, show, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I have a script that:

> - creates a new folder
> - scans an InDesign document for images
> - formats the images and copies them to the new folder

When the script is done doing all of this I want it to bring to focus the new folder directory (in Windows).

As of now I am displaying the folder-path in an alert window, but I would rather it open the directory (if it isn't already) so the user can see the new files.

---

I wish I could just call one of these:

- `myNewFolder.bringToFront()` :  works only on program focus, i.e. --                                                             `BridgeTalk.bringToFront("photoshop")`
- `myNewFolder.open()` :  seems to apply only to file I/O operations
- `myNewFolder.show()` :  seems to apply only to the  `Window`  object

...but none of these work.

---

**EDIT**:   `new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`  does not work either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the execute method.

```
myFolder.execute();
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't see it see it before on jongware, but looking at the Folder object again I now see it on http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Folder.html. Anyway, thanks @Loic!